# Correlation between Pthreads and corresponding task_struct in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have created multiple threads in userspace using pthreads but when I search the list of task_structs I only find one entry corresponding to the main thread of the userspace program. I am unable to find one entry for each userspace pthread. Why is this? How can i enumerate each pthread separately within the kernel?

Comment: Hey, I have the same question as this. Did you ever find an answer?